# How filter Scan of HBase by part of row key?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have HBase table with row keys, which consist of text ID and timestamp, like next:

```
...
string_id1.1470913344067
string_id1.1470913345067
string_id2.1470913344067
string_id2.1470913345067
...
```

How can I filter Scan of HBase (in Scala or Java) to get results with some string ID and timestamp more than some value?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to get. Give an example of what do you want and what have you tried?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, for example, if I have only 4 keys (like in question), and I want to get only with _string_id2_ and with timestamp more than _1470913345000_, I will get result with only one last key

Comment: Can you give a detailed explanation of your need and what have you tried? Something vague like this is not solvable.

Comment: go through hbase-the-definitive guide https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781449314682/ch04.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolve my problem by using to filters:
 - `PrefixFilter` (I put to this filter first part of row key. In my case - string ID, for example "string_id1.")
 - `RowFilter` (I put there two parametres: first - `CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL`, second - all my row key with necessary timestamp, for example "string_id1.1470913345000"

In result I get all cells with row key, which has necessary `string_id` if first part, and with timestamp more or equal than I put in filter in second part. It is exactly what I want.

Code snippet:

```
val s = new Scan()
s.addFamily(family.getBytes)
val filterList = new FilterList()
filterList.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(prefixOfRowKey)))
filterList.addFilter(new RowFilter(CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(valueForBinaryFilter.getBytes())))
s.setFilter(filterList)
val scanner = table.getScanner(s)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped to find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Fuzzy row approach is efficient for this kind of requirement and when data is is huge : 
As explained by this [article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781492024255/ch04.html)
FuzzyRowFilter takes as parameters row key and a mask info.

In example above, in case we want to find last logged in users and row key format is `userId_actionId_timestamp` (where `userId` has fixed length of say 4 chars), the fuzzy row key we are looking for is `????_login_`. This translates into the following params for FuzzyRowKey:

```
FuzzyRowFilter rowFilter = new FuzzyRowFilter(
 Arrays.asList(
  new Pair<byte[], byte[]>(
    Bytes.toBytesBinary("\x00\x00\x00\x00_login_"),
    new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})));
```

Would suggest to go through hbase-the-definitive guide -->[Client API: Advanced Features](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781492024255/ch04.html)

Answer (score -2):

Lets say you somehow ended up having your lines in a monadic traversable structure like List or RDD. Now, you want to have only the strings with `id = "string_id2"` and `timestamp > 1470913345000`.

Now what is the problem here ? Just filter you traversable monadic structure on these two criteria.

```
val filtered = listOrRddOfLines
  .map(l => {
    val idStr :: timestampStr :: Nil = l.split('.').toList
    (idStr, timestampStr.toLong)
  })
  .filter({
    case (idStr, timestamp) => idStr.equals("string_id2") && (timestamp > "1470913345000".toLong)
  })
```

Comment: No, you don't understand me. I need to construct such request to HBase, which will return me necessary result. But If I will use your implementation, I will be need to upload all data from HBase table and after that filter it. It not so good solution, in my opinion

Comment: Like I said in my comments. I could not understand your requirements.