# How to access HBase table records based on regions from Talend BigData Studio

Tags: hbase, talend

I am trying to access Hbase table records based on region from Talend BigData Studio. Do we have any option to filter records in tHBaseInput component based on regions.
And also how to filter records in tHBaseInput to filter the incremental records based on a date column?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for this component?  https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tHBaseInput You might be able to achieve that using the `family` filter, depending on how your families are setup.

Comment: In the documentation, there is a filter of data only based upon rowkey and not based on region

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can’t limit hbase scan to specific region.

- To be specific Hbase is good at random read and write provided rowkey is strong and salting implemented correctly which distributes data correctly.
- Filter on row key is faster but filter on columns require full scan which slow down the Hbase performance.

Also as you have more columns in column family you will see performance impact. Beyond 3 Column family it’s really works slow.

> before using Hbase you have to be sure your search pattern for data.

Kindly go through link to understand more about it

[filter-scan-of-hbase-by-part-of-row-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896467/how-filter-scan-of-hbase-by-part-of-row-key)

Salting in Hbase
[how-to-scan-salted-apache-hbase-tables](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/06/how-to-scan-salted-apache-hbase-tables-with-region-specific-key-ranges-in-mapreduce)